# MSSQL changing a return value only if it pass a Boolean_expression

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

i want to do something like this

```
SELECT (if T.EndTime = '00:00:00' THEN '23:59:59' ELSE T.EndTime) AS EndTime from Table AS T
```

i know the solution should be simple but i just cant find away to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a CASE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
SELECT
   CASE T.EndTime
      WHEN '00:00:00' THEN '23:59:59'
      ELSE T.EndTime
   END
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is  what you are looking for:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN T.EndTime = '00:00:00' 
             THEN '23:59:59' 
             ELSE T.EndTime END) AS EndTime 
from Table AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      CASE EndTime
         WHEN '00:00:00' THEN '23:59:59'
         ELSE EndTime
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column *T.EndTime* is of data type `DateTime`, you might want to convert the value to string first. So, the query would be something like this. Value **8** used in Convert function returns datetime in the format `hh:mi:ss`. You can find the list of formats for Cast or Convert at [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, T.EndTime, 8) = '00:00:00' THEN '23:59:59'
            ELSE T.EndTime
        END
FROM    dbo.TableData T
```